# Binary search tree with special operations

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Assume we have the normal binary search tree over integers.

I am interested in the number of elements that are multiples of 3 and greater than a given number x. Also, I am interested in the number of elements that are multiples of 3 and strictly between two given numbers x1,x2 with x1 < x2.
The naive approach would be for example to search the number x and then check each number if it is a multiple of 3. Is there a way to modify the binary search tree, such that these two operations are more efficiently

Comment: Is it always a multiple of *3*? Then you can filter the elements when inserting them.

Comment: @NicoSchertler In this case, I am only interested in multiples of 3. But filtering is not an option for me, because maybe I want to do  other operations with the tree later

Comment: You could always maintain two trees - one complete and one with only multiples of 3. Depends on what you really want to do.

Comment: Does x < x1 < x2 hold? If yes, then you only need to care about x1 and x2 .

Answer (score 1):

In every node, you can keep a count of the number of multiples of 3 in that node's subtree.

These counts can be maintained without changing the complexities of add/remove/rotate/rebalance operations.

Then to count the number of multiples of 3 greater than x, you search for x.  Whenever you go left at a node (because it's > x), you add the count from that node, and subtract the count from the node you move to.

If you find x in an internal node, add the count from its right child.